# Ambiguous PDO Statement - Php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1052

So, I'm trying to get all the comments for a certain course. The way it tells what course has which comments is by the course.php?cID=1563 for example. The cID is the identifer which performs this distinction.

**It keeps throwing this fatal error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'cID' in where clause is ambiguous' PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 thrown on line 42**

**DB Structure for (2) tables:**
[image: tables]

**PHP:**

```
<?php
// Get course information cID, prefix, code and dept info : name
$cID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'cID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!$cID) {
    echo "No cID specified.";
    exit;
}
$username = "###";
$password = "###";
$pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=####', $username, $password);
$pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
    SELECT Co.info, Co.date
    FROM Course C, Comment Co
    WHERE C.cID = Co.cID
    AND cID = ?;
    ;');
$sth2->execute(array(
    $cID
));
?>
```

**PHP Calling the above:**

```
<?php
                    // Did we get any *course detail*
                    if($sth2->rowCount() > 0) {
                        $row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        echo "<img class='left' style='margin:5px;' src='img/courseComment.png'/> <p> {$row['info']} </p>";
                        } else {
                        echo "No results.";
                    }
                unset($sth2);
                ?>
```

Why does this happen? If someone could please help me with an explanation and code fix that would be greatly appreciated. Also The url has the cID of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see (from your question) why you need to reference the Course table at all. The data you're returning is completely from the Comment table. I assume you have a previous query that pulls the Course info, and now you're getting the associated comments. If this is correct, a slightly better version of your code might be:

```
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
    SELECT Co.info, Co.date
    FROM Comment Co
    WHERE Co.cID = :id;
    ');

$sth2->bindParam( ':id', $cID, PDO::PARAM_INT );

$sth2->execute();
```

I'm a little rusty on what the symbols from your Visio graph mean, but if there can be multiple Comments for one Course, you would want a `fetchAll()`, not `fetch()`, and would need to iterate over the resulting array. If there can be only one Comment per Course, you could combine this query into the previous query with a `JOIN` on the `cID` field.

Answer (score 6):

You are referring to a `cID` column which exists in both tables. Update your query (`$sth2`) to point to only one of the tables, like so:

```
SELECT Co.info, Co.date
    FROM Course C, Comment Co
    WHERE C.cID = Co.cID
    AND C.cID = ?;
```

Comment: He also has an extra semi-colon at the end.

Comment: Hans isnt your answer the same as mine? It works, but I dont see why.

Comment: Tables Course and Comment each have a column called `cID`. If you have a statement like this where you are querying data from both tables, you need to clarify and tell the SQL server which column you want: `Course.cID` or `Comment.cID`. In this case it looks like you could use either.

Comment: In this statement, what you're doing is essentially the same `SELECT ... WHERE C.cID = ? AND Co.cID = ?`.

Comment: @Tieson: Ah, true, but that won't cause any fatal errors (at least not in MySQL).

Comment: @user700070 No, you left the table reference off the field name in your WHERE clause. Since you're referencing two tables, your field references must be of the form `table_name.field_name` for any fields in both tables that have the same name. That is what @Hans Engel is telling you above.